# Bootstrap 3, how to keep col-md-# from stacking?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know I can use col-xs-# to keep columns from stacking, but I have inherited a site when everything uses col-md-#. The site looks fine when the browser is full screen, but when you resize it to around 50% of the screen the columns stack even though there is still a lot of screen real estate. How can I redefine the col-md-# classes to not stack, so I don't have to find & replace all of them with col-xs-# ?

**Full Screen**
[image]

**Browser width 1100px**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can customize Bootstrap the way you want before download it.

For version 3, take a look at this page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints

The default value of `@screen-md` param is **992px**. Above this viewport width the columns (`.col-md-*`) will render side by side.
Althought I think this is not a best practice, all you have to do is lower this value to something **above 768px** (the previous breakpoint).

**Important!** Don't lower this value to **less than 768px** or you'll end up into serious grid issues.

I strongly recommend you to find-and-replace all `col-md-` to at least `col-sm` for your project.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question, adding the following CSS should do the trick.

In the first line of the media query, change 600px to the breakpoint where you want to stop the columns stacking.

```
@media (min-width: 600px){

.col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
    float:left;
}

.col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
}

.col-md-4 {    
    width: 33.33333333%;
    float:left;
}

.col-md-6 {
    width: 50% !important;
    float:left;
}
}
```

Good luck

Comment: You're telling him to handle just part of the issue, changing just few of the `col-md-*` classes.

Comment: @ed1nh0, agreed that this may not be a complete solution, and I don't disagree with your suggestion.  I'm simply offering this as an option that answers his question.